# Getting no valid OpenPGP data when importing apt key

Tags: apt, repository

I am having trouble adding a Release.gpg public key to my apt-key keyring.

I downloaded the Release.gpg file which looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.11 (GNU/Linux)

iEYEABEKAAYFAlNrkrEACgkQQJdur0N9BbV7RgCfbZGjC7ejdU5fMW6Kbk6bRQcS
G2sAn1h7znlqgxolQdsflkjsfOhYVAnsfmu96aTbiQIcBAABCgAGBQJTa5KxAAoJ
sh8yat4QALTR1k1DKijcCu9NHWm0p5iz6+cFOmUnYS8ewjhS3Oy5mk9WjXLTpOID
...
SyHY769UejhfsMeCGjsLjee5jRg2moS421UmBZbeRgicH92BUaWzL
=7r4e
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

I then ran the command `apt-key add Release.gpg`, but I get this error message:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Comment: You might need to save the file as `.asc`.